# Is it possible to multithread this Powershell NSLookup script?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, networking, dns, nslookup

I wrote a powershell script that takes in a text file of IPs and outputs a csv of the IP to hostname mapping.

Currently, the script is single threaded and is taking a long time to run since it has to wait for the DNS server to resolve the address before moving to the next IP in the list.

The recent set of IPs I needed to resolve was around 3000 addresses and took around 3 hours, and as we get to other sites in the project this number is only going to get bigger.

```
$watch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$watch.Start()
$ip_file = Get-Content -Path "C:\filepath\ip_list.txt"
$ip_list = @()

ForEach ($ip in $ip_file) {
    $ip_list += $ip
}

Write-Output "Total Number of IPs in IP File: $($ip_list.Length)"
$ip_list = $ip_list | Select-Object -Unique
Write-Output "Total Number of IPs with duplicates removed: $($ip_list.Length)"

$count = 0
$total_resolved = 0
ForEach ($ip in $ip_list) {
    try {
        $hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip).Hostname
        Add-Content -Path "C:\filepath\nslookup_results.txt" -Value "$ip, $hostname"
        Write-Output "$ip, $hostname"
        $total_resolved += 1
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Unable to resolve hostname for $ip"
    }
    $count += 1
    if ($count % 10 -eq 0) {
        $remaining = $ip_list.Length - $count
        $percentage = ($count / $ip_list.Length) * 100
        $percentage = [Math]::Round($percentage,1)
        $percent_resolved = ($total_resolved / $count) * 100
        $percent_resolved = [Math]:: Round($percent_resolved,1)
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output "IPs left: $remaining"
        Write-Output "IPs attempted: $count"
        Write-Output "Total hostnames resolved: $total_resolved"
        Write-Output "Percent resolved: $percent_resolved"
        Write-Output "Percent complete: $percentage%"
        Write-Output "Total elapsed time:  $($watch.Elapsed.Hours):$($watch.Elapsed.Minutes):$($watch.Elapsed.Seconds).$($watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds)"
        Write-Output ""
    }
}

$remaining = $ip_list.Length - $count
$percentage = ($count / $ip_list.Length) * 100
$percentage = [Math]::Round($percentage,1)
$percent_resolved = ($total_resolved / $count) * 100
$percent_resolved = [Math]:: Round($percent_resolved,1)
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "IPs left: $remaining"
Write-Output "IPs attempted: $count"
Write-Output "Total hostnames resolved: $total_resolved"
Write-Output "Percent resolved: $percent_resolved"
Write-Output "Percent complete: $percentage%"
Write-Output "Total elapsed time: $($watch.Elapsed.Hours):$($watch.Elapsed.Minutes):$($watch.Elapsed.Seconds).$($watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds)"
Write-Output "IP resolution complete!"
Write-Output ""
$watch.Stop()
```

I am curious if there is a way to utilize multi-threading in the script so that multiple DNS queries can me resolved simultaneously.

To be honest I am not sure where to start with multi-threading in powershell, as I am newer to the language, so I haven't tried to implement it myself so far. I can't afford to break the working script right now due to the time constraints I am under.

Comment: This function might do what you're looking for https://github.com/santisq/PS-NetScanners/blob/main/Test-ICMPConnectionAsync.ps1 definitely could use some refactoring tho

Comment: I have a script that parses zone files stored locally and looks up a few thousand records in about 10 minutes using a single thread/loop to do DNS lookups, so it must be something more than needing multiple threads.

Comment: The issue is that this customer has close to 14 different domains, so I can't have local zone files to read for everything because they aren't able to pull all of them for me. Also most of what I am trying to identify is using DHCP because a lot of the devices are workstations or scientific instruments. The script he provided gave me guidance on what to do to fix it. You have to do the domain lookup as a Task and then you can run multiple queries at once.